# How is virtual work defined?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, work, definition

Let $S$ be a system with $g$ degrees of freedom, $\Sigma_g$ its configuration space and $\{q_i\}_{i=1}^g$ the lagrangian coordinates. If $P\in\Sigma_g$, we define a [virtual displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) from $P$ as follows (using Einstein's convention)

\begin{equation}
\delta P=\frac{\partial P}{\partial q_i}\delta q_i.
\end{equation}

As far as I understand $\left\{\frac{\partial P}{\partial q_i}\right\}_{i=1}^g$ is a basis for the tangent space in $P$, i.e. $T_P\left(\Sigma_g\right)$.

What I don't  understand is the definition of [virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) for a force $\boldsymbol{F}$:

\begin{equation}
\delta W=\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\delta P.
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{F}$ is a vector of ordinary space, while $\delta P$ is a vector of tangent space (that has dimension $g$). If the definition I wrote above are correct, why is dot product possible?

Please note that I am taking an undergrad course in Classical Mechanics and I've never taken any courses in differential geometry.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203600/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79533/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think this has something to do with evaluation of $F$ and $\delta P$ at a point (as opposed to evaluation at multiple points) within the base manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Because the $\delta P$ is a vector too: the virtual displacement vector that always lies in the tangent space.